# Do I need a Transit Visa for layover at London Heathrow Airport?

Tags: air-travel, transit-visas, layovers

My wife has a Visitor Visa for Canada and daughter has Study Permit for Canada which is valid more than six months from the date they are travelling.

They have a layover at London for 6 hours which does not cross the day meaning day of landing and boarding the next flight is on the same day.

So, do they require a Transit Visa? I have already gone through the [tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) to check the same but I could not understand last question which says ask your airline whether you need to pass the border control.

Comment: Are they flying both legs on the same booking? If they don’t and they have checked luggage, they will most probably have to go through passport control to reclaim the bags and check them back in.

Comment: Yes that is same booking.

Comment: Provided both flights land at/depart from the same airport, then the answer to that question is most probably that they don’t need to go through passport control. Without full details of the airline and the two flights it’s difficult to be 100% sure but it’s nearly certain.